# Outputting a custom field in PHP

Tags: php, custom-field

I am a complete newbie at PHP so please forgive me. I am wanting to display some data in the following format:

> "Post name" - "Custom Field String (in this case, 'custom_date')"

I am currently using the following PHP code

```
$output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$page->ID.'"><span>'.apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, get_post_meta($post->ID,'item_',TRUE), $current_custom_date = $page->$custom_date ) .' - ' . $current_custom_date . '</span>';
```

The title and the dash are displaying perfectly. However, the Custom Field String is just displaying "Array" so now looks like this.

> "Post name" - Array

How would I get this to display the custom_date correctly? I've already set get_post_meta to 'true' as you can see so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the third parameter of `get_post_meta` to `true` does not guarantee that you get a string. What that parameter does is control how many rows of the database get returned. When `true` you only get a single result and not an array of all of the rows in the database that match. You will get a single value but it will only be a string if you've saved a string to the database. If you've saved an array, you will still have an array.

There is a note in the Codex about this:

> If you fetch a serialized array with this method you want $single to
>   be true to actually get an unserialized array back. If you pass in
>   false, or leave it out, you will have an array of one, and the value
>   at index 0 will be the serialized string.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

It sounds like that is what is happening. The data associated with your `item_` key is an array (serialized) in the database and so it is still an array even though it is a "single" result. I can't with confidence tell you how to retrieve that but it should be something like:

```
$my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'item_',TRUE);
echo $my_meta[0]; // or
echo $my_meta['some_key'];
```

In the context of your code you wouldn't need the echo because you are using the string not printing it.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. A few lines below that indicate that posts is either saved as an array or grabbed as an array:

`                    foreach( $values as $position => $id ) 
                                    {
                         $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array('menu_order' => $position, 'post_parent' => str_replace('item_', '', $key)), array('ID' => $id) );
                        }`. Now I just need to figure out how to grab them as strings. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't "grab" them as strings, not directly from the database. You just use the keys of the array (or a loop) to extract the part of the array as a string. The two `echo` lines demonstrate that.